# Building function to give linear regression equation

Tags: r, regression, function

So with the help of my TA, we were able to make build this function:

```
lm_eqn <- function(model){mod_frame <- broom::tidy(model)
eqn_string <- sprintf("The response is equal to %.2f ", mod_frame$estimate[1])
    model_terms <- function(i){
        if(i == 1){return(",")}
      paste(sprintf("+ %.2f %s", mod_frame$estimate[i], mod_frame$term[i]), model_terms(i-1))
  }
  r2 <- format(summary(model)$r.squared, digits = 3)  
  print(paste(eqn_string, model_terms(nrow(mod_frame)), "R2 =", r2))
}
```

The problem is that it spits off the regression equation in reverse order of the predictor variable categories and in reverse order of how they were listed in any model.

For example:

```
lmod <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + hp + disp, data = mtcars)
lm_eqn(lmod)
The response is equal to 34.18  + -0.02 disp + -0.01 hp + -1.23 cyl , R2 = 0.768"
```

Additionally, is there a way to add a superscript for the $R^2$?

Comment: This looks like an R programming question that should go on stack overflow?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the regression coefficients with `coef`, without having to dig into the guts of your model object. Then use vectorised `paste` to build your string from the vector of coefficients and their names.

```
lm_eqn <- function(model)
{
    b <- coef(model)
    names(b)[1] <- ""  # default name for intercept term is '(Intercept)'
    eqn <- paste(format(b, digits=3), names(b), collapse=" + ")
    rsq <- format(summary(model)$r.squared, digits=3)
    cat("The response is equal to", eqn, ", Rsquare =", rsq, "\n")
    invisible(model)
}
```